# PII Encryption problem on registration page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encryption, pii

I am having trouble encrypting my PII. Everytime I try something new, nothing works. This    is the base of my code for registration. I'm just starting out and I am having a hard time   figuring this out. Need help on how to go about fixing the issue. What I intend to do is to ecrypt all PII going in to my Database

```
`Parent
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Parent Registration";

    var textBoxClasses = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "class", "form-control" },
        // { "readonly", "readonly" },
    };

}
<head>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

</head>

@if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query.TryGetValue("error", out var errorString))
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        @errorString
    </div>
}
<div class="text-center container-fluid row text-primary">
    <h1 class="display-4 long-rounded fw-bold">Registration</h1>
    <p class="fw-bold text-dark">
        Register a BabyPedia account
    </p>
</div>
<script>
      
    var checkForm = function (form) {
        var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
        var email = form.Email.value.trim();
        var username = form.UserName.value.trim();
        var firstname = form.FirstName.value.trim();
        var lastname = form.LastName.value.trim();
        var address = form.Address.value.trim();

        if (email === "") showError("EmailError", "Email cannot be left blank.");
        if (username === "") showError("userNameError", "Username cannot be left blank.");
        if (firstname === "") showError("FirstNameError", "First Name cannot be left blank.");
        if (lastname === "") showError("LastNameError", "Last Name cannot be left blank.");
        if (address === "") showError("AddressError", "Address cannot be left blank.");

        if (email.length === 0 || username.length === 0 || firstname.length === 0 || lastname.length === 0 || address.length === 0) {
            return false; // Prevent form submission
        }

        if (response.length === 0) {
            var errorElement = document.getElementById("captchaError");
            errorElement.innerText = "Please complete the reCAPTCHA.";
            errorElement.style.display = "block";
            errorElement.style.color = "red";
            return false; // Prevent form submission
        }

          if(!form.tos.checked) {
            alert("Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions");
            form.tos.focus();
            return false;
          }
          if(!form.personalcheck.checked) {
            alert("Please indicate that your personal data will be uploaded to the internet");
            form.personalcheck.focus();
            return false;
          }

        function showError(elementId, errorMessage) {
            var errorElement = document.getElementById(elementId);
            errorElement.innerText = errorMessage;
            errorElement.style.display = "block";
            errorElement.style.color = "red";

        }
        

            var username = form.UserName.value;
            // Check if username is in email format
            var emailRegex = /^[^\s@@]+@@[^\s@@]+\.[^\s@@]+$/;
            if (emailRegex.test(username)) {
                alert("Username cannot be in email format.");
                return false; // Prevent form submission
            }

          return true;
        };
      
</script>
<form id="registrationForm" class="container-fluid row" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)" method="post" action="/register-parent">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, htmlAttributes: textBoxClasses)
            <label for="UserName">User Name</label>
            <div id="userNameError" class="text-danger"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, htmlAttributes: textBoxClasses)
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)
            <div id="EmailError" class="text-danger"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, htmlAttributes: textBoxClasses)
            <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
            <div id="FirstNameError" class="text-danger"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, htmlAttributes: textBoxClasses)
            <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
            <div id="LastNameError" class="text-danger"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address, htmlAttributes: textBoxClasses)
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Address)
            <div id="AddressError" class="text-danger"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-check mb-2">
            <input name="tos" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="toscheck">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="toscheck">
                I agree to the <strong>Terms of Service</strong> and <strong>Privacy Policy</strong>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check mb-2">
            <input name="personalcheck" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                I understand that personal data will be uploaded to the internet
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-column d-flex justify-content-between">
            <a href="/home/login" class="mb-2 nav-link">Already have an account?</a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="bi bi-arrow-bar-right"></i> Register
</button>
</div>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lcx37YmAAAAAISNDMnLkBcnEH2hg7dCBMJSRK6d"></div>
<div id="captchaError" class="text-danger"></div>
       
</div>

</form>
       `
```

Comment: You don't have to *encrypt* PII, nor does encryption protect against all leaks. It protects against theft of the database files or backups. Databases *already* offer encryption in various forms and some of them are transparent to the application, like SQL Server's [Transparent Data Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16). Backups can be encrypted already. HTTPS guards against interception of form POSTs and SQL Server connections already use TLS encryption by default